# How to batch row data and send a single JSON payload?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, aws-lambda

I currently use a Google Apps Script on a Google Sheet, that sends individual row data to AWS API Gateway to generate a screenshot. At the moment, multiple single JSON payload requests are causing some Lambda function failures. So I want to batch the row data and then send as a single payload, so a single AWS Lambda function can then perform and complete multiple screenshots.

How can I batch the JSON payload after iterating the data on each line in the code below?

```
function S3payload () {
  var PAYLOAD_SENT = "S3 SCREENSHOT DATA SENT";
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // Use data from the active sheet
  
  // Add temporary column header for Payload Status new column entries
  sheet.getRange('E1').activate();
  sheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('payload status');
  
  var startRow = 2;                            // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;        // Number of rows to process
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();      // Last column
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, lastColumn) // Fetch the data range of the active sheet
  var data = dataRange.getValues();            // Fetch values for each row in the range
  
  // Work through each row in the spreadsheet
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];  
    // Assign each row a variable   
    var index = row[0];     // Col A: Index Sequence Number
    var img = row[1];   // Col B: Image Row
    var url = row[2];      // Col C: URL Row
    var payloadStatus = row[lastColumn - 1];  // Col E: Payload Status (has the payload been sent)
  
    var siteOwner = "email@example.com";
    
    // Prevent from sending payload duplicates
    if (payloadStatus !== PAYLOAD_SENT) {  
        
      /* Forward the Contact Form submission to the owner of the site
      var emailAddress = siteOwner; 
      var subject = "New contact form submission: " + name;
      var message = message;*/
      
      //Send payload body to AWS API GATEWAY
      //var sheetid = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(); // get the actual id
      //var companyname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName(); // get the name of the sheet (companyname)
      
      var payload = {
        "img": img,
        "url": url
      };
      
      var url = 'https://requestbin.herokuapp.com/vbxpsavc';
      var options = {
        'method': 'post',
        'payload': JSON.stringify(payload)
      };
      
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
      
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, lastColumn).setValue(PAYLOAD_SENT); // Update the last column with "PAYLOAD_SENT"
      SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Make sure the last cell is updated right away
      
      // Remove temporary column header for Payload Status    
      sheet.getRange('E1').activate();
      sheet.getCurrentCell().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
      
    }
  }
}
```

Example individual JSON payload

```
{"img":"https://s3screenshotbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/realitymine.com.png","url":"https://realitymine.com"}
```

[image]

Example desired output result

```
[
    {"img":"https://s3screenshotbucket-useast1v5.s3.amazonaws.com/gavurin.com.png","url":"https://gavurin.com"},
    {"img":"https://s3screenshotbucket-useast1v5.s3.amazonaws.com/google.com.png","url":"https://google.com"},
    {"img":"https://s3screenshotbucket-useast1v5.s3.amazonaws.com/amazon.com","url":"https://www.amazon.com"},  
    {"img":"https://s3screenshotbucket-useast1v5.s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow.com","url":"https://stackoverflow.com"},
    {"img":"https://s3screenshotbucket-useast1v5.s3.amazonaws.com/duckduckgo.com","url":"https://duckduckgo.com"},
    {"img":"https://s3screenshotbucket-useast1v5.s3.amazonaws.com/docs.aws.amazon.com","url":"https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-features.html"},  
    {"img":"https://s3screenshotbucket-useast1v5.s3.amazonaws.com/github.com","url":"https://github.com"},  
    {"img":"https://s3screenshotbucket-useast1v5.s3.amazonaws.com/github.com/shelfio/chrome-aws-lambda-layer","url":"https://github.com/shelfio/chrome-aws-lambda-layer"},  
    {"img":"https://s3screenshotbucket-useast1v5.s3.amazonaws.com/gwww.youtube.com","url":"https://www.youtube.com"},   
    {"img":"https://s3screenshotbucket-useast1v5.s3.amazonaws.com/w3docs.com","url":"https://www.w3docs.com"}       
]
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about `How can I batch the JSON payload after iterating the data on each line in the code below?`. In order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample input and output you expect? From these information, I would like to try to understand about your goal.

Comment: I see you have working single-row submission, great! But, where is your attempt at multiple-row submission? This is not a code-writing service. If you make an attempt and share the issues you encounter, your question will be much more well-received.

Answer (score 5):

**Modifications**

1. Do not call `UrlFetchApp` methods in a loop unless no other way. Although Google offers generous [quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), it is not unlimited, and you will quickly burn through it on any substantial amount of rows and send frequency.
2. Use modern ES6 features like [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert rows of values into objects in the format of the desired payload. Note that you will have to [enable V8 runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration#incompatibilities) to use them.

What follows is a *runnable* test snippet showcasing how you could have modified your script. I opted to exclude status update logic from it, as it is up to you to decide how to update the status in case of batch update failure:

```js
//TEST MOCKS:
const SpreadsheetApp = {
  getActiveSheet() {
  
    const Sheet = {
      getLastRow() { return 3; },
      getLastColumn() { return 5; },
      getDataRange() {
      
        const Range = {
          getValues() {
            return new Array(Sheet.getLastRow())
            .fill([])
            .map(
              (r,ri) => new Array(Sheet.getLastColumn())
              .fill(`mock row ${ri}`)
              .map((c,ci) => `${c} cell ${ci}`)
            );
          }
        };
        
        return Range;
      }
    };
    
    return Sheet;
  }
};

const UrlFetchApp = {
  fetch(uri, options) {
    console.log({ uri, options });
  }
};
//END MOCKS;

const sendToS3 = () => {

  var PAYLOAD_SENT = "S3 SCREENSHOT DATA SENT";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  var siteOwner = "email@example.com";

  const appURI = 'https://hfcrequestbin.herokuapp.com/vbxpsavb';

  const payloads = data.map(([index, img, url]) => ({ img, url }));

  const options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': JSON.stringify(payloads)
  };

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(appURI, options);
}

sendToS3();
```

---

**Notes**

1. When batching POST payloads, keep in mind that there is a quota on
   maximum body size per request (currently 50 MB).
2. Do not call I/O (input/output) methods such as `getRange`, `getValue` in a loop, they are slow by nature, use batch methods like `getDataRange`, `getValues`, `setValues`, etc and perform all modifications on in-memory arrays only.
3. Use `activate` methods only when you *explicitly* want to change the focus, do not rely on it to determine a range. Just use normal references to cells obtained through methods like `getRange`.

Comment: Nice  usage of mock. Will copy in my answers :)

Comment: @TheMaster - thanks :) Yesterday, it struck me - why remove unrannable snippets if we can mock the services?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the data as a list/Array. And on the server side iterate over the list/Array.

eg:

```
{
    "payload": [{
        "img": "https://s3screenshotbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/website1.com.png",
        "url": "https://website1.com"
    }, {
        "img": "https://s3screenshotbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/website2.com.png",
        "url": "https://website2.com"
    }]
}
```